# Two questions on the Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

I have two questions on the Gaussian integers.

1. Is any element in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ the root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$?
2. Conversely, does any element in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ that is the root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ lie in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: $a+bi$ is a root pf $x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2=0$.

Comment: i.e. $\,w\,$ is a root  $\,(x-w)(x-w') = x^2 - (w\!+\!w') x + ww'\,$ where $\,w'$ is the conjugate of $w,\,$ so $\,w\!+\!w',\, ww'\in \Bbb Q.\,$ For the 2nd question use Gauss's Lemma

Answer (score 0):

1) $a+bi$ is a root of $x^2-2ax+(a^2+b^2)=0$.

2) For the converse, consider the quadratic $x^2+bx+c$, where $b$ and $c$ are integers. If the roots are rational, they are divisors of $c$. Now we deal with the case the roots are non-real. From the quadratic formula, if the roots are non-real and in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, they are of the shape $\frac{s\pm ti}{2}$, where $s$ and $t$ are integers.

Then $\frac{s^2+t^2}{4}=c$. Thus $s^2+t^2\equiv 0\pmod{4}$. This forces $s$ and $t$ to be even, and we are finished.